# Regex to select the 2nd whitespace after a matched character

Tags: python, regex, whitespace, matching

I am trying to match the middle whitespace out of 3 whitespaces in a row.

I want to only match the middle whitespace but only if it precedes a `|`. The actual text I have to match from is this:

```
 --- --- ---
|   |   |   |
 --- --- ---
```

I can match 2 whitespaces in a row that precede `|` with `(?<!\|)\s{2}` (the `x`s represent the matches) but I only want to match the `x` in the middle

```
 --- --- ---
| xx| xx| xx|
 --- --- ---
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to split the string and use white space as separator, get the substring in the middle then match it to the regex pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grouping](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to get these specific spaces:
The **bolded section** relates to the spaces that you want:

> (|\s{3}|\s)**(\s{2})**(|\s{3}|)

#### Code:

```py
import re

text = """
 --- --- ---
|   |   |   |
 --- --- ---
 """
 
pattern = re.compile(r"(\|\s{3}\|\s)(\s{2})(\|\s{3}\|)")

match = pattern.search(text)
print(match.group(2))
```

Here is a **regex101** : [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6WRYWV/1)

- **group(0)** matches the entire pattern from start to end. `|   |   |   |`
- **group(1)** matches the pattern **before** the whitespace of interest
- **group(2)** matches the whitespace of interest
- **group(3)** matches the pattern **after** the whitespace of interest